# www.example.com Works but example.com does not work when I type in browser

Tags: domain-name-system, iis, iis-8, namecheap

I am not sure if this is an iis setting or if this is a domain hosting setting. but when I do something like example.org it will go to my site but if I just type in chrome example.org(http://example.org/) it does not work.

I tried to add in namecheap another cname with "*" pointing to my DNS name of my vm.

I have in namecheap

```
A Record: @ | ip address
Cname: * | websites721.cloudapp.net
Cname: www | websites721.cloudapp.net
```

Comment: Give us the domain name. `www.example.com` and `example.com` are totally separate FQDNs and you need records for both.

Comment: Re: your edit - you presumably need to point the `@` (which is your `example.com`) at the `websites721.cloudapp.net` address instead of an IP. See https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9646/10/how-can-i-set-up-a-cname-record-for-my-domain

Answer (score 0):

First, a note about the difference between an `A record` and a `CNAME`. The former maps a domain name, e.g.: `somesite.somedomain` to an IP address. e.g.:`192.168.0.256`, while the latter maps a name, e.g. `somesite.somedomain` to another name `www.somesite.somedomain`.

In your `DNS Zone File`, in addition to your `A record`, you'll need to add an entry similar to this:

- Name: www
- Type: CNAME
- Value: @

Comment: When I do this in name cheap it says. Warning setting up Cname for a naked domain will cause email issues.